# jquery unable to append data to unique html element

Tags: jquery

I'm pretty stuck with the following :

I have table rows set from wich I select data values from each row and send them to .post request (by clicking Calculate button appended to each row). Till here - Ok, I gather different data from each row. But when I try to append the .post result to a row input field I can't manage to append it just to the row, it is appended to the whole row set. Any idea why ?

```
$('a.calculate').click(function(e) {

   e.preventDefault();

   var a = $(this);
   var start_date = a.parents('tr').find('input.first-date').val();
   var end_date = a.parents('tr').find('input.last-date').val();

   $.post( "calculate.php", {start_date: ""+start_date+"", end_date: ""+end_date+""}, function(data){
            a.parents('tr').find('input.price').val(data);
   });

});
```

Comment: Let's see the HTML, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of your html but a possible error i see is the use of `.parents('tr')`.

`parents('tr')` will return all ancestors that are `tr` so depending on your html (*nested tables*) it might go outside of the row.. and the subsequent `find('input.price')` might match multiple elements.

Try using [`.closest('tr')`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) which will stop to the first one it finds..

```
$('a.calculate').click(function(e) {

   e.preventDefault();

   var a = $(this);
   var start_date = a.closest('tr').find('input.first-date').val();
   var end_date = a.closest('tr').find('input.last-date').val();

   $.post( "calculate.php", {start_date: ""+start_date+"", end_date: ""+end_date+""}, function(data){
            a.closest('tr').find('input.price').val(data);
   });

});
```

Comment: Thank you, it works ! I have not published the html code since the input.price field is placed in the same order as the elements from which the data was successfully taken.

Answer (score 0):

Please share the HTML as well. Could be a formatting error.

Little code cleanup:

```
$('a.calculate').click(function(e) {

   e.preventDefault();

   var a = $(this),
       tr = a.parents('tr').first(),
       start_date = $('input.first-date', tr).val(),
       end_date = $('input.last-date', tr).val();

   $.post( "calculate.php", {start_date: ""+start_date+"", end_date: ""+end_date+""}, function(data){
            $('input.price', tr).val(data);
   });

});
```